# .bash_profile PS1 to show current directory folder and a $ MAC osx

Tags: bash

In my .bash_profile I currently have

```
PS1="$ "
```

which in my terminal returns '$ '

I want to show the current folder as well.

if I run the command, pwd
/Users/Me/Sites/

I would want my bash prompt to return
'Sites$'

Thanks for all your help.

Comment: See http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Controlling-the-Prompt specifically `\W` and `\w` and `$PROMPT_DIRTRIM`.

Comment: thank you for the `\W` that returned the current directory only.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

try this:

```
PS1='\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[01;34m\] [\w]\[\033[00m\]'
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. I shortened it up a bit and my final code was `'PS1='\[\033[01;34m\][\W]\[\033[00m\]$ '` which displayed the current director in green and a $

Answer (score 7):

Note that if you don't want brackets or colors surrounding the current directory, you can use the simpler:

```
export PS1="\W$ "
```